# Solve the following system of equations in the set of real numbers.

Tags: systems-of-equations

$z(y^2-x^2)=16$,
$y(z^2-x^2)=9$,
$x(y^2-z^2)=5$
The best relationship I found is  $16xy=9xz+5yz$, but that doesn't seem very useful either. With the help of Wolfram and I found out that the system has 2 real solutions, but I really don't know how to get them. This system seemed very simple, but I came up with terrible calculations. Can you help me please ?

Comment: Please show your calculations in your your question post, so we can see where you possibly went wrong.

Comment: Also, please post, in your question, how you derived $16xy=9xz+5z$, and how you think is shows a relationship.

Comment: The equations are correct. And one solution is $x=1, y=3, z=2$. The other solution is ugly.

Comment: @Moo  please don't answer in comments.

Comment: This site is not a do my work for me site.

Comment: I got $z^2=4/(x+y)+xy$ and $z=16xy/(9x+5y)$, but I don't think they are useful relationships because they are too complicated.

Comment: You can eliminate one variable first.

Comment: I also got similar relations for $x$ and $y$, but are ugly too. I really want to slove this system but I can't get more that this useless things. I will apreciate every hint or idea.

Comment: Then look up $res(f,g)$, the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant). It factors very nicely here, see my answer.

Comment: Yes, that is what I tried to do. I eliminate the variable z, but the calculations are too ugly.

Comment: @JosieMcLaren Please do not vandalize posted questions, including your own. Rolled back.

Comment: Please do not deface the question. Changing a question invalidates the answers and comments already posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computational way is to eliminate $z$ by $z=16/(y^2-x^2)$. This gives two equations $f(x,y)=0$ and $g(x,y)=0$. The resultant is a polynomial only in, say, $y$, and the roots are the common solutions. Here we have the product of three factors, namely
$$(y-3)(y^2+3y+9)(3y^3+4)=0.$$
The first factor gives $(x,y,z)=(1,3,2)$, the second factor has no real solutions, but two complex solutions $y$ with $3z=2y$ and $3x=y$,
and the third one gives another real solution, with the cube root of $-4/3$.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems correct, you have the same solutions as Wolfram, but could you explain to me in a little more detail how you got the result?

Comment: As I said above, use the resultant for these two polynomials $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the resultant, not the result. I didn't really understand how to calculate the resultant, but now I understand. The problem is that I obtained 2 polynomials in which the maximum degree of x is 6, respectively 5, so the determinant has the order 11 and not even Wolfram could calculate it for me. However, you managed to calculate it, so I assume that you obtained other polynomials, although I do not see how you could reach a lower degree. Could you please tell me how you proceeded to get this beautiful resultant?